# PHP Asyncronous call to Objects Methods

Tags: php, oop, asynchronous, methods, call

Is there any way to make asyncronous calls to PHP objects methods? Using jquery I could .load en external file into div, but then I wouldnt be able to access methods like setTemp below. I want to avoid having to "wait" for one object to update before the second update is initiated..

My (failed) attempt looks like this, three files:

beachregister:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>OO Method test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                $("#BaiadoSancho").load();
            }, 60000);
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                $("#GraceBay").load();
            }, 60000);
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    include 'Baiadosancho.php';
    include 'Gracebay.php';

    $baia = new Baiadosancho;
    $baia->setTemp();

    $grace = new Gracebay;
    $grace->setTemp();

    // .... lots of other beaches
    ?>

    <div id = "BaiadoSancho">
        <?php $baia->setTemp(); ?>
    </div>

    <div id = "GraceBay">
        <?php $grace->setTemp() ?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Baiadosancho.php

```
class Baiadosancho{
private $temp;

public function getTemp() {
    return $this->temp;
}

public function setTemp() {
//        $json = file_get_contents('urltogettemperature');
//        $arrayDecodedFromJSON = json_decode($json, true);
//        ...
//        $this->temp = $arrayDecodedFromJSON['temp'];
}

}
```

Gracebay.php

```
class Gracebay {

private $temp;

public function getTemp() {
    return $this->temp;
}

public function setTemp() {
//        $json = file_get_contents('sampl/temperature');
//        $arrayDecodedFromJSON = json_decode($json, true);
//        ...
//        $this->temp = $arrayDecodedFromJSON['temp'];


}

}
```

..I have also considered other means like the ones below, are they favorable you think?

GearMan, Parallel cURL execution in PHP, EvPeriodic and iron.io

Comment: why new gracebay with brackets and new baiadosancho without brackets?

Comment: If you want *asynchronous* execution, then you will have to resort to something like Gearman or possibly forks. Standard PHP is single threaded and not evented.

Comment: @MrJack Just a mistake, corrected, thank you

Comment: @deceze I was afraid so. I was hoping it was possible with jquery though. With the below code I can load a file and have its content loaded into div, is this not asynchronous? The problem I have with the below code is that the $baia and $grace objects (and methods) are not available for "filetoload.php".

$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {
$("#BaiadoSancho").load("filetoload.php");
}, 300000);
});

Comment: Well, if you invoke those actions from the client side, then yes, you can fire off several requests in parallel which will run asynchronously as seen from the client. However, as I understood your question, you want PHP to start such asynchronous tasks, in which case see above comment.

Comment: @deceze Thank you for taking the time answering me, you have been of great help. I think I will give Gearman a go. But.. The solution does not need to be pure PHP. If the "same result" is possible with jquery (make several json requests simultaneously) then I would try that first.

For this the objects would have to "be available" to (passed to?) "filetoload.php". Is this possible, do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer(s) to my question are as follows:

As deceze wrote:
If you want asynchronous execution (in standard PHP), then you will have to resort to something like Gearman or possibly forks. Standard PHP is single threaded and not evented.

It is possible using jquery though, and how to access objects from requested file is explained here:
[Using objects in Ajax calls PHP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216098/using-objects-in-ajax-calls-php-files)